# How to show less content lines using jsom in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom

In need to develope page like below
[image: 1]

```
if(theString.length>100){
   theString = theString.substr(0,100)+'...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like below to truncate the string variable:

```
function truncate(input, noOfChar) {
   if (input.length > noOfChar) {
      return input.substring(0, noOfChar) + '...';
   }
   return input;
};
```

Usage:

```
theString = truncate(theString, 100);
```